# What is wrong with my DOB Sorting script

Tags: bash, unix

I keep getting an error on line 22: [!: command not found

My script Asks for a name, phone number, and date of birth and then amends these details to a comma separated value file called “birthday.csv”.

It then Sorts “birthday.csv” by date of birth. The newly sorted file is then displayed and calculates their age.

Can someone take a look at my script and see why this is popping up.

```
#!/bin/bash

a=0
while [ $a -lt 2 ];
do
    echo Please enter a first name
    read firstName
    echo Please enter last name
    read lastName
    echo Please enter phone number
    read phoneNumber
    echo Please enter date of birth - format dd/mm/yyyy
    read dob
    echo "$firstName,$lastName,$phoneNumber,$dob" >> userBirthdays.csv
    echo If you would like to add another person press 1 or enter 2 to proceed
    read a
done

    INPUT=./userBirthdays.csv
    OLDIFS=$IFS
    IFS=","
    [! -f INPUT] &  while read Name Surname Telephone DOB
    do
                    birthMonth=${DOB:0:2}
                    birthDay=#10${DOB:3:2}
                    birthYear=${DOB:6:4}

                    currentDate=`date +%d/%m/%Y`

                    currentMonth=${currenDate:0:2}
                    currentDay=#10${currentDate:3:2}
                    currentYear=${currentDate:6:4}

                    if [[ "$currentMonth" -lt "$birthMonth" ]] || [[ "$currentMonth" -eq "$birthMonth" && "$((#10$currentDay))" -lt "$((#10$birthDay))" ]]
                    then
                            let Age=currentYear-birthYear-1
                    else
                            let Age=currentYear-birthYear
                    fi

            echo "Name : $Name"
            echo "Surname : $Surname"
            echo "Telephone : $Telephone"
            echo "DOB : $DOB"
            echo "Age : $Age"
            echo "##########################################"
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
    echo $DATE

exit 0;
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a space between between the [ and ! chars, i.e.

```
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && while read ....
#^-^--------^-^---^------------
```

Note that you almost certainly want two '&' chars, as in my correction.

Thanks to @GordonDavisson for another '$' ;-)

IHTH

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that should be `$INPUT` (or better yet, `"$INPUT"`, although it doesn't actually matter in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Separate `[` and `!` with a space, so `[` will be a command, and `!` will be its first argument, as you meant them to be.

(Not sure there are no other problems).